# <a class="page-button next ng-star-inserted">next </a> does not contain href link. How to transverse all the next pages in Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to use scrapy to transverse pages after the next button on a webpage. But I found that there is no href links where the next button is. How can I do this if there is no ref links? Everything suppose to be in next  . how to get the ref link?

[screen shot of where next button is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oWIZ.png)

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy cannot interpret javascript.
You need to use selenium to click and get or click the link.

```
from selenium import webdriver

class your_spider_name(Spider):
    name = 'xxx'
    allowed_domains = ['www.example.org']
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.org']

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self,response):
            self.driver.get('https://www.example.org/example')

            while True:
                try:
                    next = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="BTN_NEXT"]')
                    url = 'http://www.example.org/example'
                    yield Request(url,callback=self.parse2)
                    next.click()
                except:
                    break

            self.driver.close()

    def parse2(self,response):
        print 'you are here!'
```